# Increase value of data row of particular ID on button click

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

In my application customers book vehicle online & admin of site assigns duty to drivers which are already added. Below screen shot you can see the list of drivers.

Now what I am trying to do is if admin assigns some duty to some driver then in assign duty column should count which driver get how many duties. e.g. if admin assign duty to first driver then duty assign column should be updated by 1. Is it possible to do so? Below my code to assign duty to drivers

VB

```
    Protected Sub assignDuty_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles assignDuty.Click
        Dim Did As String
        Did = DriversList.SelectedItem.ToString
    Try
        Dim str1 As String = "UPDATE newBooking SET Assigned = '" & Did & "', status = 'Approved', DriverContact = '" + driverMobile.Text + "', vehicleNo = '" + vehicleNo.Text + "'  WHERE Bid = '" & trackInput.Text + "'"
        Dim data As MySqlDataReader
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        command.CommandText = str1
        command.Connection = con
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        con.Open()
        data = command.ExecuteReader
        con.Close()
        send_customer_message()
        send_driver_message()
        customer_confirm_mail()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

    Protected Sub DriversList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DriversList.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM addDriver where DriverID='" + DriversList.SelectedValue.ToString + "';"
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            con.Close()
            orderStatus.Visible = True
            additionalDetail.Visible = True
            vehicleNo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("VehicleRegistration").ToString
            driverName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("DriverName").ToString
            driverMobile.Text = dt.Rows(0)("contact")
            'duration.Text = dt.Rows(0)("duration")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

UPDATE!

How admin assigns duty to drivers. 
Admin receives mail when customer books online. He simply enters booking ID & click track orders & all details will be displayed in left side part. In right side he has list of drivers & he selects one & on select last section vehicle details get updated & finally he clicks on assign duty so databse get updated in newBooking table.

UPDATE!

```
Protected Sub assignDuty_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles assignDuty.Click
        Try
            Dim Did As String
            Did = DriversList.SelectedItem.ToString

            Dim Query1 As String
            Query1 = "UPDATE newBooking SET Assigned = '" & Did & "', status = 'Approved', DriverContact = '" + driverMobile.Text + "', vehicleNo = '" + vehicleNo.Text + "'  WHERE Bid = '" & trackInput.Text + "'"
            RunCommand(Query1)

            Dim Query2 As String
            Query2 = "UPDATE addDriver SET [DutyAssigned] = [DutyAssigned] + 1 WHERE DriverID = " & Did
            RunCommand(Query2)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Function RunCommand(ByVal myQry As String) As String
        Try
            Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("constr")
                Using _comm As New MySqlCommand()
                    With _comm
                        .Connection = _conn
                        .CommandText = myQry
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    End With
                    _conn.Open()
                    _comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
            RunCommand = ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            RunCommand = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Can you explain more about how admin will be assigning duty to specific driver?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Thanks for reply. I have updated my posy please go through it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code. Here you need to specify your connection string in RunCommand method. Let me know the results.

```
Protected Sub assignDuty_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles assignDuty.Click
    Try
        Dim Did As String
        Did = DriversList.SelectedItem.ToString

        Dim DriverID As String
        DriverID = DriversList.SelectedValue

        Dim Query1 As String
        Query1 = "UPDATE newBooking SET Assigned = '" & Did & "', status = 'Approved', DriverContact = '" + driverMobile.Text + "', vehicleNo = '" + vehicleNo.Text + "'  WHERE Bid = '" & trackInput.Text + "'"
        RunCommand(Query1)

        Dim Query2 As String
        Query2 = "UPDATE addDriver SET DutyAssigned = DutyAssigned + 1 WHERE DriverID = " & DriverID
        RunCommand(Query2)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function RunCommand(ByVal myQry As String) As String
    Try
        Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("connectionStr here")
            Using _comm As New MySqlCommand()
                With _comm
                    .Connection = _conn
                    .CommandText = myQry
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                End With
                _conn.Open()
                _comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
        RunCommand = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        RunCommand = ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry Irfan Bhai for late reply. I have updated my post & shared scrennshot of both tables.

Comment: I have seen the structure. Actually you can do this in two ways. 1. Write a stored procedure and use two queries as i mentioned in my previous reply. 2. Keep your solution as it is but execute anothet update query as below:-UPDATE DRIVERS SET [duty asaigned] = [duty asaigned] + 1 WHERE DRIVERID = DId

Comment: Please verify for column and table name in my query. I am outside so cannot write full and exact code for you. If you follow my replies carefully you can write it. Otherwise let me know i will do it once reach back.

Comment: 1. if runcommand returns any value.

2. Did has correct driver id?

Comment: Please set breakpoints at query1 and query2 and post here so that i can see how queries are being formed.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in code. please move the _conn.open up just below "Using _conn...". i think connection is not being opened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96969/discussion-between-muhammad-irfan-azam-and-stupid-romeo).

Comment: Is it Ok if you connect with me on teamviewer?

Comment: Yes we can decide on time. But if you provide me what runcommand returns and what query strings are then i can tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Give me some time you will be online. we can join a chat and if required i can connect to teamviewer to look into this issue.

Comment: When you are available?

Comment: sorry I am not accessing frequently due to project. I am online now. If we can connect now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97108/discussion-between-muhammad-irfan-azam-and-stupid-romeo).

Comment: Hey Can you please help me with this post. I am not finding any error nor output. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551323/filtering-listview-with-radiobuttonlist-selection

Answer (score 0):

1. I would encourage you to use binding parameters instead of concatinating query string (like `SELECT * FROM addDriver where DriverID=:DriverId` and `cmd.Parameter.Add("DriverId",MySqlType.Varchar,<fieldLength>,"DriverId"`. Do it also in the Update query.)
2. In `assignDuty_Click` you should use `UpdateCommand` instead of `SelectCommand` (I´m no MySql pro but SelectCommand smells for me).
3. For updating the Duty Assigned field enhance the Update string in `assignDuty_Click` with `SET DutyAssigned = DutyAssigned + 1 ...` (or whatever the field is named in newBooking).